# Setting a UIimage view equal to another UIimage View

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, uiimageview

I am making a little animation type of app for a project. I have a space to draw images on an imageView. Then when you click the new page button I need the image in that imageview to move into another imageview I have on the timeline. Hopefully you understand my problem if not let me know what other information you need.

Comment: so both the imageviews are in the same view, right?

Answer (score 1):

hai Check This code This will allow you to draw any image and then you can access your image using method getimage in nsdata format. and then you can convert it into image from nsdata

```
.h File
//
//  SignatureCaptureImageView.h
//  TEST_DRAW_APP
//

 1. List item

//  Created by Talat Masud on 8/23/10.
//  Copyright 2010 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface SignatureCaptureImageView : UIImageView {

    CGPoint lastPoint;

    BOOL mouseSwiped;   
    int mouseMoved;
}
-(NSData *)getImage;

@end


Implementation File


#import "SignatureCaptureImageView.h"


@implementation SignatureCaptureImageView


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        // Initialization code
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        mouseMoved = 0;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage*)image {
    if ((self = [super initWithImage:image])) {
        // Initialization code
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        mouseMoved = 0;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) 
    {
        //self.image = nil;
        return;
    }

    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    lastPoint.y -= 5;

}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    mouseSwiped = YES;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    currentPoint.y -= 5;


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
    [self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;

    mouseMoved++;

    if (mouseMoved == 10) {
        mouseMoved = 0;
    }

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        //self.image = nil;
        return;
    }


    if(!mouseSwiped) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
        [self.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        self.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}

-(NSData *)getImage{
    return  UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image);
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

declare 2 UIImageViews , first with the image and second without any image, ie., empty UIImageView, but having an origin and size.

Then, when u want to animate, do the following,

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect sframe = mSecondImgView.frame;
                     mFirstImgView.frame = sframe;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }];
```