# creating iphone application with UIViewController and Cocos2D

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I need to create an application in which user can select background image from gallery and draw (like pencil drawing) on it. Any code or hint.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link. You can set image using Method initWithImage. and can get back your image using getImage Method

[Setting a UIimage view equal to another UIimage View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659614/setting-a-uiimage-view-equal-to-another-uiimage-view/6659700#6659700)